# (Batch) Subtract value directly in if statement?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, variables

can I directly subtract a number from a variable in an if statement (example 1), or do I have to subtract the value before and then check for the new value (example 2)? And which would be the correct syntax, if method 1 would work?

**example 1:** `if "%variable%-1"==%other_var% ()`

**example 2:** `set variable_minus_1="%variable%-1"; if %variable_minus_1%==%other_var%`

Comment: Not sure if you are talking substitution or subtraction, but assuming substitution. you can match it directly.. let's assume `set "var=123"` and we we want to test is the last value here is 3 `if %variable:~-1% equ 3`

Comment: if however you are talking about subtraction. i.e `set num=4` and want to subtract one to get three `set /a num-1` then you need to do `set /a num-1` then `if %num% equ 3`

Comment: Just a quick correction for the above, it should read, `set /a num -= 1`, to decrement by one. This information along with the rest of its usage is available by entering `set /?` in a Command Prompt window. You can also get the help page for the `if` command using `if /?`.

Comment: thank you all very much for helping me out so quickly :)